# How can I have more clicks than page views in AdSense

Tags: google-adsense

One of my AdSense ad units (in the new beta interface) occasionally says that I have more clicks than page views which gives a CTR of over 100%.  Does anyone know how this happens?  I'm assuming it has something to do with when a page view is recorded, versus when someone clicks, but it happens regularly enough (on a daily report) that it can't just be that a bunch of users click an ad before the page displays fully.

Comment: hey this isnt an answer but what is page views on google analysts it says i have less page views than adsence, are they diffrent?

Comment: Bobby, the count different things. The difference between the PAGE having a view and an AD having a view. Also, they update at different frequencies so there may be a lag.

Answer (score 5):

Users could also be right-clicking which causes a new window to open which allows them to click again. Or they could be clicking an ad and then clicking back and doing it again.

I don't believe the back button reloads the page so that would not record a page view but the click through would be recorded if they click a second link.

Answer (score 3):

Text ad units can display many ads per unit - 4 to 5 are visible at once but often you will see an arrow to scroll through more ads. Same thing goes if you have multiple ad units per page. A user could click all of those ads.

If you have more than a handful of visitors (>100 a day) then this is very unlikely since the number of people who don't click any ads usually outweighs the number who click, massively.

Comment: You are right this happens when the visitor counts are low either due to a very restrictive custom channel (a single page) or when the statistics are viewed very early in the day. Just because the numbers would eventually hide this anomaly doesn't mean that it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have number of clicks greater than page views. When a user clicks on your ad the user is taken to a new webpage however when the user clicks on back button on new page it is not recorded as new page view on your website. You should be very careful and closely monitor your website statistics and [report this activity to adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/invalid_clicks_contact?hl=en&rd=2) as some one might be trying to click bomb you.

Normally the people who don't click your ads are far much greater in number than people who click your ads and normal websites have page CTR ranging anywhere from 1%-6%.