# Adsense clicks without any page views

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Today (2014-10-20) I noticed that on one website of mine I got two adsense clicks without any page views. How is this possible? And should I worry about violating adsense policies?

This question is very similar but also quite different:
[How can I have more clicks than page views in AdSense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-can-i-have-more-clicks-than-page-views-in-adsense). The answers don't apply at all if there are no page views at all (i.e. right clicking, a user clicking more than one ad).

Here's a screenshot I just took:
[image: screenshot]

Update: It's still 0 and 2 a day later. Meanwhile I'm seeing it also on another website today, with 1 click for 0 page views.

Update 2015-01-29: I saw 1 click and no page views, in the afternoon. Half an hour later it indicated 2 page views. I guess adsense might show clicks before page views in some cases.

Comment: Dang good question. I wish I had an answer! One up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Adsense clicks and views are not in real time (they seem to be updated at set periods through the day). Also, there is a possibility that somebody (or more than one person) loaded the page before midnight and then clicked on one of the adverts after midnight. Possible example:

1. User loads the page at 11.30pm.
2. The user's attention drifts to another tab or page (or they are interrupted by an external source).
3. At 12.07am, the user re-focuses their attention on your page.
4. 12.08am: The user clicks on an advert that interests them.

Comment: Just noticed this situation at 12:30am. So very likely to be what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when the clicks are just after midnight.   The page views actually come from the day before and are attributed to the previous day.

Comment: I checked and it is a possibility. There was only one pageview the day before though, so the odds are quite low. But the *0 pageviews n clicks* is also quite rare of course. I'm upvoting and leaving it open as there might be another reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am an Adsense Publisher since 2006. Sometimes Adsense is giving a not so updated figure, just wait for 24hours and you will see you have a page views